# Renaming package breaks JNI function Android studio

Tags: java, android-studio, opencv, java-native-interface

I am working with openCV and it was working fine till I changed the package name.I search through the google and stackoverflow but nothing worked out.
It's been a day and I am frustrated.
Here is the log cat.
Any help will be appreciated.

```
12-18 08:37:24.328 12081-12144/in.indilabz.in.cbxprint E/art: No implementation found for void in.indilabz.in.cbxprint.editor.filter.PhotoProcessing.nativeApplyFilter(int, int, long, long) (tried Java_in_indilabz_in_cbxprint_editor_filter_PhotoProcessing_nativeApplyFilter and Java_in_indilabz_in_cbxprint_editor_filter_PhotoProcessing_nativeApplyFilter__IIJJ)
12-18 08:37:24.333 12081-12144/in.indilabz.in.cbxprint E/UncaughtException: java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
                                    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:304)
                                    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
                                    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
                                    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
                                    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
                                    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
                                    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
                                    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
                                Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for void in.indilabz.in.cbxprint.editor.filter.PhotoProcessing.nativeApplyFilter(int, int, long, long) (tried Java_in_indilabz_in_cbxprint_editor_filter_PhotoProcessing_nativeApplyFilter and Java_in_indilabz_in_cbxprint_editor_filter_PhotoProcessing_nativeApplyFilter__IIJJ)
                                    at in.indilabz.in.cbxprint.editor.filter.PhotoProcessing.nativeApplyFilter(Native Method)
                                    at in.indilabz.in.cbxprint.editor.filter.PhotoProcessing.processImage(PhotoProcessing.java:26)
                                    at in.indilabz.in.cbxprint.editor.fragment.RecyclerMenuFragment$GetFilterThumbsTask.doInBackground(RecyclerMenuFragment.java:144)
                                    at in.indilabz.in.cbxprint.editor.fragment.RecyclerMenuFragment$GetFilterThumbsTask.doInBackground(RecyclerMenuFragment.java:134)
                                    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:292)
                                    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                                    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231) 
                                    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112) 
                                    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587) 
                                    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818) 
12-18 08:37:24.459 696-714/? E/SensorService: activeConnections...
12-18 08:37:24.459 696-714/? E/SensorService: activeConnections...
12-18 08:37:24.625 12081-12144/in.indilabz.in.cbxprint E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #3
                                Process: in.indilabz.in.cbxprint, PID: 12081
                                java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
                                    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:304)
                                    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
                                    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
                                    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
                                    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
                                    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
                                    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
                                    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
                                Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for void in.indilabz.in.cbxprint.editor.filter.PhotoProcessing.nativeApplyFilter(int, int, long, long) (tried Java_in_indilabz_in_cbxprint_editor_filter_PhotoProcessing_nativeApplyFilter and Java_in_indilabz_in_cbxprint_editor_filter_PhotoProcessing_nativeApplyFilter__IIJJ)
                                    at in.indilabz.in.cbxprint.editor.filter.PhotoProcessing.nativeApplyFilter(Native Method)
                                    at in.indilabz.in.cbxprint.editor.filter.PhotoProcessing.processImage(PhotoProcessing.java:26)
                                    at in.indilabz.in.cbxprint.editor.fragment.RecyclerMenuFragment$GetFilterThumbsTask.doInBackground(RecyclerMenuFragment.java:144)
                                    at in.indilabz.in.cbxprint.editor.fragment.RecyclerMenuFragment$GetFilterThumbsTask.doInBackground(RecyclerMenuFragment.java:134)
                                    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:292)
                                    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                                    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231) 
                                    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112) 
                                    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587) 
                                    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Comment: JNI generates the names of the native functions from the Java classes using the `javah` tool.  The generated names include the package, class, and method name, including the parameter and return types.  So if you changed the name of the package, you will have to rerun `javah`, and then you will have to change the implementations of all the native functions to match the new generated header files.  This is why you're getting UnsatisfiedLink errors...the Java VM can't find methods in your native .so with the right names to be the implementation of your class's native methods.

Comment: I'm not sure it's worth the trouble to rename the package.  You're legally required to disclose that your project uses OpenCV (per [the OpenCV license](https://opencv.org/license.html)) so I'm not sure what motivation you would have to embed it under your own package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the comment from @lockcmpxchg8b, I went to look for references on javah & found [this article](http://intellij.my/2017/05/10/how-to-create-a-c-library-with-ndk-on-android-studio/) where I figured out the answer.

To solve this, you need to check the make file (maybe in somewhere like `app/src/main/jni/Android.mk`). It should contain values like `LOCAL_MODULE`, `LOCAL_CFLAGS` & `LOCAL_SRC_FILES`.

LOCAL_SRC_FILES would have some .cpp files listed. Find the function(s) in one of the files that has a name like `Java_old_package_name_editor_filter_PhotoProcessing_nativeApplyFilter` & change `old_package_name` to your new package.

Comment: In my case, I haven't found any Android.mk in the project, but I've found some functions in _.cpp_ files with `Java_old_package_name_...`. After renaming them, the project worked, as expected. 

Also, for me, the functions' names were collapsed, so I didn't notice them at first.